# Can I archive my Flutter app version I am debugging on the iOS simulator without build it?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

When I archive my Flutter app in Xcode (expecting the new changes I made and see in the simulator be on the archived version), it archives with the previous version before I made changes.

So always I make this long time process: close the app from the simulator, launch it from Xcode (instead of VSCode debugger), wait the build process to finish then run the archive and wait again so long to finish the archive. However, this process takes too much time, especially when I change the flavor from preproduction to production, it takes more than 10 minutes to build and archive.

**Is there any way to archive the version I am debugging in the simulator?**

I'm not sure if this could be the reason, but I've heard that the version I see in the simulator is  incompatible with real devices due to their architecture differences. The simulator uses the x86 architecture, while Apple devices use ARM architecture. I am using an M2 processor, so does the simulator still uses the x86 architecture?.

**Is there any way I can speed up the app building process without having to wait so long for the initial build, and then waiting again for the archiving?**

Comment: A debug build is different to an archive build that you submit to the App Store. You might want to look into CI platforms that can create your archive build in the cloud.